# How to delete dated txt files as part of a bash script under linux

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script, which is part of a larger script to generate the files, which deletes the dated backups after so many days. They are in the form of `test-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d.txt")`

This is what I've got, which isn't really working;`find ~/cron/obnam -type f -mtime +3 | xargs rm>>$LOG-FILE 2>&1`

This is to be used on Debian 7, under Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% accurate, but maybe this is good enough for the case that you describe:

```
find ~/cron/obnam -type f -mtime +3 -name 'test-*.txt' -exec rm -v {} + >>$LOGFILE 2>&1
```

If you have some corner cases that this does not handle well, please drop a comment and I will amend.

Comment: This works well as written, thanks janos, but is it possible to substitute $NUM-LEFT in place of +3 and declare it at the beginning of the script please?

Comment: You could write `-mtime +$NUM` if you defined earlier `NUM=3`, not sure if that's what you're asking. You could even do `-mtime MTIME` and `MTIME=+3`

Comment: Brilliant janos, thank you. $NUM is working well, and my whole script is now under beta testing for a couple of weeks. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

for generality, i like functions:

```
findtest() { find ~/cron/obname -type f -mtime +${1:-3} -name 'test-*.txt'; }
```

lists the candidates. e.g.

```
findtest      # default is 3 days
findtest  31  # say for 31 days
```

then

```
trimtest () { findtest ${1:-7} | xargs rm -v ; }   # and executed

trimtest >> $LOGFILE
```

this way separates action ( the finding, ) policy ( remove after N days), and recording ( appending to the log file).  depending on your needs, you might also rewrite to pass the whole flag, and allow both **older** or **newer** options.

good luck.

Comment: Might as well use the `-delete` flag for `find` (if available) or use a more robust method so that it copes well with filenames containing funny symbols like spaces, so that generality doesn't mean breakability.